# ManagementEventWatcher on a Windows Service works in debug but not on install

Tags: c#, windows, service, executable, managementeventwatcher

Apologies ahead of time if I did not indent my code properly, this is my first post. So my end goal is to create a Windows Service that watches events for when a notepad.exe process is started and in response launches mspaint.exe. This is my first time working with Windows Services but I've been able to get this code to work as a Console Application and as the Windows Service while in debug mode. However, whenever I go to install it and test as a release, it installs fine and starts up with no problem but when I launch notepad.exe nothing happens.

```
**MyNewService.cs**
public MyNewService()
{
InitializeComponent();
System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"Initialized.txt");
}
public void OnDebug()
{
OnStart(null);
}
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Start();
}
protected override void OnStop()
{
System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");
}

static void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
string instanceName = ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"])["Name"].ToString();
if (instanceName.ToLower() == "notepad.exe")
{
Process.Start("mspaint.exe");
}
}
}
**Main Program**
static class Program
{
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if DEBUG
MyNewService myService = new MyNewService();
myService.OnDebug();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
new MyNewService()
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Established that the Service does in fact work. The problem was that it runs as localSystem once installed which only does background services and does not have access to the visible desktop. It was launching the paint.exe in invisible mode. See link below:

https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/5a5uof/advice_managementeventwatcher_on_a_windows/

Comment: Hmm, no, that doesn't explain why it worked when you used the Debug build of the service.  Maybe your question wasn't very accurate, do fix it.

Comment: I used a service installer that installed and ran the service under local system. Debug was ran in IDE and not under local system. Debug and Build accomplished the same thing, only build did so in background. This was confirmed by monitoring task manager with the "Show all user" check box.

This was developed to put a third party software into maintenance mode via command prompt when patching occurs. Since we did not need to see the command prompt it did in fact work as needed. This code has been in a large scale production environment since November and has experienced no issue.